# Is there any way to kill vb.net windows application reference

Tags: vb.net, window

We have a vb.net windows application which is deployed on a shared server and multiple usersare using its reference on their local machines.

Problem:  Whenever we want to deploy a new version then we have to close all the instances used by the application which is not feasible so we need to find and kill all the references of the application forcefully with every deployment.

We are using active directory credential to login to the application.
so we need to find all active directory user who are using the application instance.

Please let me know is there any way to kill vb.net windows application reference forcefully used by multiple users.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you have a single executable on a shared server, and multiple users are executing that executable from that location.

If this is the case then the answer is to package and deploy the executable properly (i.e. on to the local users machine)! A good solution would be [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), which is a Microsoft technology to allow really simple deployment and upgrade of client applications. I would recommend it.